SqlAlchemy selectively returns TypeError when querying dates from sqlite
I'm running into the following issue while trying to build a web app using sqlite3, Python and SqlAlchemy. When I attempt to query the database for datetime.date data, SqlAlchemy raises a TypeError but it only does so when it's not using filtering - i.e. when not using filter_by() or filter().
Please find below an overview of the main components that relate to this problem (abbreviated for conciseness).
I created the database using this model:
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guests (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                check_in NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                check_out NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                )""")

I have the following SqlAlchemy model:
class Guest(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "guests"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    check_in = db.Column(db.Date, nullable = False)
    check_out = db.Column(db.Date, nullable = False)

I am obtaining user input via an html date field. I confirmed that type(check_in) is datetime.date.
        check_in = request.form.get("check_in")
        if check_in:
            try:
                check_in = datetime.strptime(check_in, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            except ValueError:
                return f.error("Invalid input - check-in date")

In a separate function, I'm implementing a guest search functionality. Problem is, I am seeing a "TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str" when I try to query the database without filtering (on the else statement). This error does not get raised when the query uses the filters dictionary.
            from utils.models import Guest
            guests = []
            query = db.session.query(Guest)
            if filters:
                for key, value in filters.items():
                    if isinstance(value, list):
                        query = query.filter(getattr(Guest, key).in_(value))
                    else:
                        query = query.filter(getattr(Guest, key) == value)
                    guests = query.all()
            else:
                guests = query.all()

Full traceback:
[2024-09-17 10:22:43,444] ERROR in app: Exception on /search_guest [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\WebApp\project\app.py", line 929, in search_guest
guests = query.all()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2673, in all
return self._iter().all()  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1769, in all
return self._allrows()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 548, in _allrows
rows = self._fetchall_impl()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1676, in _fetchall_impl
return self._real_result._fetchall_impl()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 2270, in _fetchall_impl
return list(self.iterator)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 219, in chunks
fetch = cursor._raw_all_rows()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 541, in _raw_all_rows
return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "lib\sqlalchemy\cyextension\resultproxy.pyx", line 22, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy.BaseRow.init
File "lib\sqlalchemy\cyextension\resultproxy.pyx", line 79, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy._apply_processors
File "lib\sqlalchemy\cyextension\processors.pyx", line 51, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.processors.str_to_date
TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str
From what I've been reading online, the problem might have to do with SQLite's reliance on type affinities rather than strictly imposed data types and the fact that the check_in/ check_out data might be saved as an integer rather than a string. Unfortunately, that does not explain why SqlAlchemy raises this error only when querying without filter_by() or filter().
Any insight would be much appreciated.
In the end, I am looking to handle the situation where a user does not provide any search parameters because they want to see all the records, but I would also like to understand the root cause of the problem to gain a deeper understanding of how SqlAlchemy operates and ensure that I can systematically avoid such issues moving forward.

Your table likely contains inconsistent data in the check_in and/or check_out columns, e.g., where dates are stored like 20240917 (integer) instead of '2024-09-17' (string). If you convert all of those integer values to their corresponding string (date) values then your app should behave more reliably.

@GordThompson : Thank you for the suggestion. I already checked the data and it is correct and consistent. The problem seems to be somehow related to SqlAlchemy as I have managed to get around the error by replacing guests = query.all() with guests = query.filter(Guest.id > 0).all() which does indeed return all records. So it would appear that the filtering methods are processing the data in some way that mitigates the issue. Problem is, I have no idea what triggered the initial error and this is a rather rudimentary fix.

So if you do select count(*) as n from guests and select count(*) as n from guests where id > 0 do you get the same number?

@GordThompson: Yes, because the id is set to autoincrement so it selects all the records which have a positive id. I have also been testing this with a small database where I can visually confirm that the check_in and check_out data is present and formatted correctly.

This is almost certainly caused by bad data. Since the error occurs when SQLA is converting the raw data into a date object the filters likely filter out the bad row(s) from the dataset.
